# New SharePoint list types

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience

I have been reading this article https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/Enrich-your-SharePoint-Content-with-Intelligence-and-Automation/ba-p/194174 where I see in the section 'Build new lists' many other options like Travel project and inventory

[image]

Do I need to do anything on my site/tenant to get the same options?

Answer (score 0):

The feature may have been pulled back. See: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-SharePoint-Blog/Create-SharePoint-lists-from-Excel-or-other-lists/ba-p/533395#M4279

In any case:

- You access it from the Site Contents page and the New dropdown there. (You may not have access to all of the options, and at least for me, they do not look like what was proposed in your linked article.)
- Are you setup for "Targeted Release"? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/manage/release-options-in-office-365?redirectSourcePath=%252fen-us%252farticle%252fSet-up-the-Standard-or-Targeted-release-options-in-Office-365-3B3ADFA4-1777-4FF0-B606-FB8732101F47&view=o365-worldwide